# How to disable page/form in JSF

Tags: jsf

For my application I want to have users with different permissions.  One permission would allow a user to view the data from my database, while another permission would allow them to edit the data.  On log in I would check their permission to determine wether they can edit the data.  I am looking for some way to disable the entirety of my page if the user has the read-only permission.  Is there a simple way to disable everything within the `<h:form>` tag?  I would need to be able to disable multiple pages, hopefully by just looking at one boolean in by backingbean.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-EDIT-
Is there any containers or like that I could wrap around my inputs that could be set to disabled?  This way I would only need to reference the diable in one place and could also leave each field to set its own disable property if that is needed in other logic I have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the buttons, links, input fields (everything that allows editing) etc... pointing them all to the same value in the backing bean.

```
<h:inputText disabled="#{!bean.permissionToWrite}">
```

I don't know any way to disable everything contained in a form, but you may not want to do that because you may want the user to submit search queries (i.e. a search box) withing the form.

**Update**: answering to the comment of Alex Larzelere.

IMHO in this case is better to use `disabled` rather than `rendered` because you may want to display the value of a field to the user in an `inputText` box, but not let him to modify it. If you don't render it, he can't see it. You could use `outputText` as well to display it but then you have to maintain two elements instead of one.

**Update** answering to the edit in the question:
You can wrap your components inside a `h:panelGroup` for example and render it or not depending on your logic, but you can't disable the input fields that are inside from the `h:panelGroup`, you have to do it individually.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it.  An alternative is to use `rendered` and just hide anything that gives the ability to edit from users who are not authorized to do so.

Comment: That could be an option, though that will be a lot of work. I was hoping there would be something more elegant like (which I know is not possible) `<h:form disable="#{bean.permission}" />`

Comment: is not that much work, when adding an element, just add the disable parameter. Even in the future you could group permissions according to roles or groups for example :)

Comment: @pakore : Your way is correct. BUT WHAT IF I WANT TO DISABLE A BUNCH OF COMPONENTS TOGETHER? If I use **disabled** attribute for each component then it will generate individual HTTP REQUESTS for each component to fetch same value from BEAN!!!!!

Comment: @Kishor you can use a variable. Or you can even improve my answer without using caps.

Comment: This answer is not the best anymore. The last update is invalid (was not valid from the beginning). The other answers provide solutions of which mine is the least work (using http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute)

Comment: Well I answered 7 years ago...I guess the framework has changed since then :)

Answer (score 5):

This simple custom component can be used to wrap other components and it will disable them if used with the attribute disabled="true" or an EL expression evaluating to true. The way it's intended to work is that if a wrappped component is already disabled then it won't get enabled if disablePanel is used (or ajax re-rendered) with disabled="true". The component only attempts to disable UIInput & UICommand components, which I think is ok but could be changed.

```
xmlns:fnc="http://myco.co.uk/fnc"
...
<fnc:disablePanel disabled="#{bean.isItDisabled}">
   <h:inputText/>
   ...
</fnc:disablePanel>
...
```

UIDisablePanel.java

```
package uk.co.myco.component;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.component.*;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

/*
 * @author Brendan Healey (Oversteer)
 */

@FacesComponent("uk.co.myco.component.UIDisablePanel")
public class UIDisablePanel extends UIComponentBase {

    private enum PropertyKeys {
        disabled;
    }

    public UIDisablePanel() {
        setRendererType(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {

        boolean toDisable = isDisabled();
        processDisablePanel(this, toDisable);
        //super.encodeBegin(context);
    }

    public void processDisablePanel(UIComponent root, boolean toDisable) {

        /*
         * The key point here is that a child component of <x:disablePanel> may
         * already be disabled, in which case we don't want to enable it if the
         * <x:disablePanel disabled= attribute is set to true.
         */

        for (UIComponent c : root.getChildren()) {
            if (c instanceof UIInput || c instanceof UICommand) {
                if(toDisable) { // <x:disablePanel disabled="true">
                    Boolean curState = (Boolean) c.getAttributes().get("disabled");
                    if(curState == null || curState == false) {
                        c.getAttributes().put("UIPanelDisableFlag", true);
                        c.getAttributes().put("disabled", true);
                    }
                }
                else { // <x:disablePanel disabled="false">
                    if(c.getAttributes().get("UIPanelDisableFlag") != null) {
                        c.getAttributes().remove("UIPanelDisableFlag");
                        c.getAttributes().put("disabled", false);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (c.getChildCount() > 0) {
                processDisablePanel(c, toDisable);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        // Got to override it but it doesn't get called.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public boolean isDisabled() {
        return (boolean) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.disabled, false);
    }

    public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
        getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.disabled, disabled);
    }
}
```

disablepanel.taglib.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
    <namespace>http://myco.co.uk/fnc</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>disablePanel</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>uk.co.myco.component.UIDisablePanel</component-type>
        </component>
        <attribute>
            <name>disabled</name>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Comment: We are using this code and it worked all right until now.I found that when I have a component in my disablePanel which is enabled at first with a condition like `<p:inputText disabled="#{condition}" />` and you change that condition and update the whole disablePanel to be enabled it doesn't render the inputText correctly disabled but uses the initial disabled-state from when the view has been rendered the first time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/) has a [`massAttribute`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute) taghandler for this with several options. The one that comes closed to what you need is

```
<o:massAttribute name="disabbled" value="true" target="javax.faces.component.UIInput">
    <h:outputLabel for="input1" />
    <h:inputText id="input1" />
    <h:outputLabel for="input2" />
    <h:inputText id="input2" />
    <h:outputLabel for="input3" />
    <h:inputText id="input3" />
</o:massAttribute>
```

This disables all components that extend from `javax.faces.component.UIInput`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Tomahawk's components has displayValueOnly, visibleOnUserRole and enabledOnUserRole attributes to control elements visibility.

Hope following links will be useful to you:

- http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/DisplayValueOnly (and also /myfaces/User-role_Awareness page near)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to disable all the components from your page. Nota that, 
with this, you could also disable only a group of components at once

I put the method **disableUIComponent** inside an utility class beacuse I wanted to use it in several JSFBeans.

```
public class UtilsPrimefaces { 

/**
 * Disable all the children components
 * @param uiComponentName
 */
public static void disableUIComponent(String uiComponentName) {  
    UIComponent component = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()  
            .getViewRoot().findComponent(uiComponentName);
    if(component!=null) {
        disableAll(component.getChildren());
    } 
}  

/**
 * Recursive method to disable the list
 * @param components Widget PD list
 */
private static void disableAll(List<UIComponent> components) {  

    for (UIComponent component : components) {  
        logger.info(component.getClass().getTypeName());            

        if (component instanceof InputText) {  
            ((InputText) component).setDisabled(true);

        } else if (component instanceof InputNumber) {  
            ((InputNumber) component).setDisabled(true);

        } else if (component instanceof InputTextarea) {  
            ((InputTextarea) component).setDisabled(true);

        }  else if (component instanceof HtmlInputText) {  
            ((HtmlInputText) component).setDisabled(true);

        }  else if(component instanceof SelectOneMenu) {  
            ((SelectOneMenu) component).setDisabled(true);

        } else if(component instanceof SelectBooleanCheckbox) {  
            ((SelectBooleanCheckbox) component).setDisabled(true);

        } else if(component instanceof CommandButton) {  
            ((CommandButton) component).setDisabled(true);              
        }
        disableAll(component.getChildren());  
    }  
}
```

And then you could use in your beans. This is an example for a page that had 3 scrollPanels and I wanted to disable only panel1 and panel3:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {        
    super.init();
    if(userHasPermissions() || loadPageInReadOnly()) {
         Utils.disableUIComponent(":form:panel1");
         Utils.disableUIComponent(":form:panel3");
    }
}
```

It works for me :) 
P.S I was using primefaces 2.2

Comment: Thanks. For newer versions of every jsf, check http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute Does exactly this, but more flexible and without your own code...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep a check on performance use JQuery.
using prop property of all the elements in a form set disabled attribute to true.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formName :input").prop("disabled", true);
    });
```

You can also use boolean properties of backing bean here. For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if(#{bean.property} === true)
        $("#formName :input").prop("disabled", true);
    });
```

Comment: Can be client-side manipulated and overridden. A server side counterpart IS needed