# Need to disable all components of a JSF page(CommandLink,selectionOneRadio) after checking a one if case while onload?

Tags: jsp, jsf, primefaces, jboss

This is basically insurance project and old project as well. They have written this code with JSF and Java implementation. There are a lot of cases should work on this as this is insurance project. There are several modes for a policy such as View only mode, Edit mode, New creation mode. So, coming to the main point, when a user enters through a view only mode, he can not change anything. He can just see whatever he mentioned in that policy earlier. So all the edit icons, Change icons should be kept disabled. That disable option kept at every case. 
So we need to put it on the javascript onload and check View only mode or not the case, and should disable all the attribute types such as links, Edit options.
Main concern: it is easy for Html with JQuery
but it is JSF and jquery is fine, But for JSF, it looks different.
Do you have a solution?

This is already implemented but the disabling option is kept at every case (Checking view only mode or not the case at very edit button). So to optimize this code, we can do it on the very first page to disable all components in that page.

Comment: You may have a look at primefaces "BlockUI" or create something like this by yourself.

Comment: Use omnifaces mass attribute (doing it the jquery way is dangerous since the client can manipulate things)

Comment: and you know that JSP has been deprecated in JSF for nearly 10 years now do you? in favour of facelets

Comment: any other thatn omniface mass attribute

Comment: sure, you can copy past the code of the omnifaces mass attribute and use it in your own way... Or in other words: why any other? If you are already using JSF and PrimeFaces, Omnifaces is something that should have been used already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Disable or Enable a group of Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011481/how-to-disable-or-enable-a-group-of-components)